# Cooking with Plastic

Tags: baking, food-safety

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How dangerous is it to bake food with plastic?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29650/how-dangerous-is-it-to-bake-food-with-plastic)

I baked a cake with a piece of plastic in the oven. Is the cake safe to eat? Were the dangerous chemicals in melted plastic absorbed by the cake?

Comment: Did you intentionally put the piece of plastic or was it a part of cookware. If the plastic melted, I don't guess it is worth taking the risk.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend chucking the cake out. Many plastics contain additives which are not really recommended for eating (e.g. phthalate plasticizers, brominated fire retardants etc). The dangers are long term though for these. If the plastic is PVC - that's another matter. I would say definitely bin it and also if you can detect a weird smell or taste in the cake.