# Safe to buy food baked in plastic containers:

Tags: baking, food-safety, temperature

I recently bought some baked goods (corn break I think) from Fred Meyers, and it seesm to be baked right in the plastic container it came in.

Is this safe?

This question makes it seems like this is unsafe?
[How dangerous is it to bake food with plastic?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29650/how-dangerous-is-it-to-bake-food-with-plastic)

Comment: How do you know that they were baked in the container that you found them in? Or are you saying that they come with instructions for *you* to bake them in that container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plastic [oven bags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oven_bag) like this

[image: salmon in oven bags]

Source http://lamiacucina.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/saumon-en-papillote-au-citron-vert-lachs-in-folie/

that can be used at temperatures at least up to 200°C. I am sure that there should be equivalent baking pans with similar properties for baking goods.

In conclusion, referring to your link to another question: It depends on whether the plastic is supposed to be baked or not. The questioner of the other thread said he had forgotton to remove a piece of plastic that he had been supposed to. In your case: It is very likely safe.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, based on a review at [Cook's Illustrated](http://www.cooksillustrated.com/equipment_reviews/745-plastic-baking-pans) (paywall, but some content is visible), there do exist disposable plastic baking pans that are safe up to 400 F--and many baked goods are baked at or below that temperature.

Comment: The question I ask myself when I see tempting food cooked in plastic is "How likely is the purveyor to have taken safety concerns into account when purchasing the containers and prepping the food?"